# Is there a way to "cap" RoslynPad's Roslyn's IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, intellisense, microsoft.codeanalysis, roslynpad

I'm actually integrating the amazing [RoslynPad](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad) into a WinForms application and working damn well.

The point of the integration is allowing the user to type in some C# code so it can be used in a future.

Thing is I'm interested on "capping" the user so he could just use some System or even LinQ functions. **I don't want to allow the user to think he is allowed to use `System.IO` and others**. Of course I can't prevent him/her typing `System.IO.File.Delete`, but will surely help if the `System.IO`'s Assembly is not loaded into the RoslynPad's IntelliSense.

The source code typed by the user is going to be compiled locally before being saved into the DB. I'm adding just a few and necessary Assemblies for the compilation, so if `System.IO` it won't compile, of course.

As I explained, I just want to cap the Intellisense, so they don't think they have access to almost the whole .NET Framework.

EDIT: Added the actual implementation actually done. I'm loading "RoslynPad.Roslyn.Windows" and "RoslynPad.Editor.Windows" assemblies to the editor.

```
private RoslynCodeEditor _editor;
private void InitializeEditor(string sourceCode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceCode))
        sourceCode = string.Empty;
    _editor = new RoslynCodeEditor();
    var workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var roslynHost = new RoslynHost(additionalAssemblies: new[]
    {
        Assembly.Load("RoslynPad.Roslyn.Windows"),
        Assembly.Load("RoslynPad.Editor.Windows")
    });

    _editor.Initialize(roslynHost, new ClassificationHighlightColors(), workingDirectory, sourceCode);
    _editor.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Consolas");
    _editor.SyntaxHighlighting = HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinition("C#");
    _editor.FontSize = 12.75f;
    elementHost1.Child = _editor;
    this.Controls.Add(elementHost1);
}
```

Comment: I just took a quick look at the example editor included with the source,it looks like that list is *probably* coming from the referenced assemblies that are added with `.WithReferences()` or `RoslynHost .DefaultReferences`.  You could just not add `System.IO`, and other assemblies that you don't want the user to have..

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for your comment but looks like `.DefaultReferences` is readonly and as you can see at the edit I did on the question, I'm just addind "additional Assemblies". I'm not finding any way to specify which ones should be "just" added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pass a `RoslynHostReferences` instance to the `RoslynHost` constructor, and decide which assemblies and namespaces are imported by default.

You could use the [same logic](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/7f63cb27ae47fddd56666694785526539c6c8aef/src/RoslynPad.Roslyn/RoslynHostReferences.cs#L24) as `Default`, just remove `System.IO.Path` from the type list.

Note that `System.IO` is not an assembly, but rather a namespace, which is in the core library, so there's no simple way to completely remove it.